# C pointer lost after multiple assignments

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C programming and having some issues with the pointers in the following code. I am using the C89 standard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * b(char *p) {

    char *z;

    z = p;

    printf("b(): %s\n", z);

    return z;

}

void a(char *p, char *q) {

     q = b(p);
     printf("a(): %s\n", q);
}

void main(void) {

    char *p = (char *) malloc(15);
    char *q;

    strcpy(p, "This is a test");

    a(p,q);

    printf("main(): %s\n", q);

    free(p);
}
```

For some reason, my `printf` function is printing nothing in the `main()` function. The `printf` calls in both of the functions `a()` and `b()` are working. I am not sure why my pointer "q" is lost in the main function. I even tried allocation dynamic memory to "q" in main() function but still no results.

Comment: Your string is 15 bytes long but you allocate only 9.

Comment: I am sorry, i mistakenly allocated 9 bytes. It should be 15 in malloc(). Even after that its not working

Answer (score 4):

`q` in `main()` is uninitialized. You probably assume that `q` is changed after `a(p,q)`, but as that pointer is passed by value (as everything in C), after returning from `a`, any changes done to `q` are discarded (they were local to `a`)

To solve this, while preserving most of your function signatures, you would have to add another level of pointers

In following code, `p` and `q` in `a` are local to `a`, but you are not directly changing any of them, insted, you are modifying value, that is pointed at by `q` (that value is of type `*char`, so another ponter, easy to get lost)

```
void a(char *p, char **q) {

     *q = b(p);
     printf("a(): %s\n", q);
}

void main(void) {
    ...
    a(p,&q);

    printf("main(): %s\n", *q);

    ....
}
```

Or simply return that pointer, and assign to `q` in `main` (as you have done in `b`)

To better understand why this is happening, consider this simpler example:

```
void foo(int a) {
    print("value is %d\n", a);
    a = 42; // modifies only a local copy of passed parameter a
    print("modified value is %d\n", a);
}

int main() {
    int a = 0
    printf("initial value is %d\n", a);
    foo(a);
    printf("value after returning is (still) %d\n, a");
}
```

Comment: So, what's the solution to this issue?

Comment: @ShahJee: You could just return a char pointer from function a.

Comment: I tried the above solution. Now the main() is printing fine but a() is printing weird characters. Note: My "q" is still defined as single pointer in the main() function.

Comment: yes, i forgot that you use that q on next line. You have to dereference `q` in `a` there too.

Comment: Perfect. Working great now. Thanks geek. You are a smart guy. :)

Comment: Just a little question, what was i doing wrong initially? I just want to clear my concepts.

Comment: I have pointed that out at the beginning of my answer. all changes to `p` or `q` in `a` does not change `p` or `q` in `main`. This is because when calling `a(p,q)`, values `p` and `q` are copied. `a` only modifies these copies, and not origianl values.

Comment: I used to think that when ptr is passed to the function, it is passed by reference and not the value. Thank you for clarifying my concept.